# Initialize lil_matrix given data and coordinates

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

Here is an example of what I am tying to do:

```
my_rows = [[1, 3], [0, 2], [], [1]]
my_data = [[1,1], [1,1], [],[1]]
```

I want to create a matrix like this:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import sparse
my_lil = sparse.lil_matrix(np.array([[0,1,0,1],
                                     [1,0,1,0],
                                     [0,0,0,0],
                                     [0,1,0,0]]))
```

So

```
>>> my_lil.rows
array([[1, 3], [0, 2], [], [1]], dtype=object)
```

I feel like I am missing something very simple, as seeing how easy it is to initialize [coo_matrix](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.coo_matrix.html#scipy.sparse.coo_matrix), however I don't see anything like this for [lil_matrix](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.lil_matrix.html)

This is my best attempt:

```
my_lil = sparse.lil_matrix([[1,1], [1,1], [],[1]], [[1, 3], [0, 2], [], [1]])
```

This fails with this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('O') to dtype('bool') according to the rule 'safe'
```

I am using:

```
>>> scipy.__version__
'0.14.0'
```

Comment: Why not just initialize the `coo_matrix` and then convert it to `lil`.?

Comment: @hpaulj, after MrAlias pointed out that it is not possible to initialize lil_matrix like I want to, that was exactly what I did :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it says in Scipy's documentation the lil_matrix only supports instantiation by passing a dense or sparse matrix, or by giving the desired shape (resulting in an empty matrix).  One of the main reasons I see that lil_matrix doesn't support this form of instantiation is that the column count will be indeterminable.

Given this you could instantiate a coo_matrix, as it supports instantiation by passing data and positioning arguments, or you could create your own form of instantiation dealing with the shape as you see fit.

```
class my_lil_matrix(sparse.lil_matrix):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if len(args) >= 2 and isinstance(args[1], list):
            try:
                data, rows = args
            except:
                raise TypeError("Invalid input format")

            if kwargs.get('shape') is None:
                # Column count will just be the largest value in rows
                M, N = (len(rows), max(np.array(rows).max()) + 1)
            else:
                M, N = shape

            super(my_lil_matrix, self).__init__((M, N), **kwargs)

            self.data = np.array(data, copy=kwargs.get('copy'),
                                 dtype=kwargs.get('dtype'))
            self.rows = np.array(rows, copy=kwargs.get('copy'),
                                 dtype=kwargs.get('dtype'))
        else:
            super(my_lil_matrix, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```